# how can i fetch the name from id by using this query?

Tags: mysql, sql

there are 2 table tbl_hk and tbl_hk_work:

1. tbl_hk:hk_id(pk), hk_name
2. tbl_hk_work:hk_work_id, hk_id(fk), hk_work_date, hk_work_1bed, hk_work_2bed, hk_work_time

and I have written a query to fetch sum of hk_work_1bed, hk_work_2bed from hk_id from two dates inputted by the user and I also want to fetch hk_name with the same query but its showing error the only help I need is everything is perfect I just want hk_name to be fetched with the SUM.

QUERY:

```
SELECT SUM(hk_work_1bed), SUM(hk_work_2bed), 
  SUM(hk_work_time_decimal) 
FROM tbl_hk_work 
WHERE (hk_work_date BETWEEN '2019-10-1' AND '2019-10-1') 
  AND hk_id=1;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

all you need is to `join` your `tbl_hk` table  and `group by` `hk_name`

```
select t2.hk_name, sum(hk_work_1bed), sum(hk_work_2bed), sum(hk_work_time_decimal) 
from tbl_hk_work t1
inner join tb_hk t2 on t2.hk_id = t1.hk_id
where hk_work_date between '2019-10-1' and '2019-10-1' and t2.hk_id=1
group by t2.hk_name;
```

Comment: Error
Static analysis:

1 errors were found during analysis.

Unrecognized statement type. (near "group by" at position 0)
SQL query:

group by t2.hk_name

MySQL said: Documentation

#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'group by t2.hk_name' at line 1

Comment: it's showing this error! appreciate your effort though.Thanks

Comment: try again, i moved the semicolon

Comment: Ohh perfect it worked as I wanted to thank you so much for your help. I really appreciate it.

Comment: @MehulPanchal, don't forget to accept this answer. thanks.